# in ajax form do validation and show a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajaxform

I have this function(to make my form work with ajax):

```
$(function() {
   $('#restore_form').ajaxForm({
   beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
   success: SubmitSuccesful,
   error: AjaxError
   });
});

function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
   var queryString = $.param(formData);
   alert('BeforeSend method: \n\nAbout to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
   return true;
}

function AjaxError() {
   alert("An AJAX error occured.");
}

function SubmitSuccesful(responseText, statusText) {
   alert("SuccesMethod:\n\n" + responseText);
}
```

my form(django form) only contains a file upload field. i want also check validation and i have this function for this purpose:

```
function TestFileType( fileName, fileTypes ) {
   if (!fileName) {
      alert("please enter a file");
      return false; 
   }
   dots = fileName.split(".")
   fileType = "." + dots[dots.length-1];
   if(fileTypes.join(".").indexOf(fileType) != -1){
      alert('That file is OK!') ;
      return true;
   }
   else 
   { 
      alert("Please only upload files that end in types: \n\n" + (fileTypes.join(" .")) + "\n\nPlease select a new file and try again.");
      return false;
   }
}
```

now when i try to use validation function(TestFileType) in the first function, it doesn't work. both of them works seperately. fore example if i write the below line in onclick of submit button, it works:

```
onclick="TestFileType(this.form.file.value, ['tar.gz']);"
```

I also want instead of alerting user, show a hidden div in success function:
i have:

and i want in success function do:

```
 $('.response').html(responseText);
 $('.response').show();
```

EDIT:
Here is my template:

```
<form id="restore_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="restore/">
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {{ form.file.errors }}
        <p id="sendwrapper"><input type="submit" value="{% trans "Send" %}" id="submitButton" style="margin-bottom:10px; cursor:pointer; background-color:#F90;"/></p>            
 </form>
 <div class="response" style="display: none;"></div>
```

but it doesn't work! it seems only alert works in this function. Can you please help me?
really thanks :)

Comment: What does your form template code look like? Are you sure that the $('.response') selector is matching an element in the DOM?

Comment: i edited my question. i think it matches. thanks :)

Comment: Looks good from here. Perhaps as a sanity check in Firebug or Web Inspector's Network tab that the form isn't causing the page to reload, it would explain why an alert dialog works, as an alert would block the page reload, and if you are working locally the refresh may be so fast it's not easily noticeable.

Comment: I'll check it. but if the page is realoding, because i have break points in my code, i would understand. Can you please help me how can i use my validation function with ajax form(first function)?

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to use the AjaxForm plugin in the past and found that unless you have a very specific reason to use it, it's typically easier to write the ajax form submit code without the plugin. This is a simplified/commented version of a previous jquery ajaxform that I created using Jquery without the plugin:

```
 $('form').submit(function(event) {
    var form = $(this);

    // creates a javascript object of the form data
    // which can be used to validate form data
    var formArray = form.serializeArray();
    // (validate whatever values in formArray you need to check here);

    if (form_is_valid) {
        var formData = form.serialize(); // a URL-encoded version of the form data for the ajax submission
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: someUrl,
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
                // update success message boxes here
            }
        });
    } else {
        // update client-side validation error message boxes
    }
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from actually navigating to the action page
});
```

Hopefully this helps, I've found that the plugin can be useful at times, however I've typically found that this leads to easier to understand code and avoids the use of plugins..

Comment: thanks, yeah, you're rigth. I've used this function in my other page, but when i tried to use it here, It didn't send file. i mean there wasn't any files in my request sending to the server. It's a useful and simple function, but it seems it doesn't work fine with files. and for this reason i've used that plugin.